# How to create an Angular application using Vite?

Tags: angular, npm, yarnpkg, vite, nomachine-nx

I want to use Vite for creating an Angular app with basic routing, minimal options, and no testing files and open in port 5000

Searched all over and not got.

Comment: I believe that Angular v16 uses Vite now. See this article: https://blog.angular.io/angular-v16-is-here-4d7a28ec680d

Answer (score 4):

Vite does not support Angular and vice-versa. The reason being, that the Angular CLI does more than the React CLI, for example, and also uses its own compiler called `ngc`.

Comment: It is supported now for angular 16+, you can check the [doc](https://angular.io/guide/esbuild#vite-as-a-development-server)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's true that there is no default support for *vite* in angular project, and not to forget it is because of the fact as @forbiddencodding has mentioned that angular needs the the custom angular compiler `ngc` to compile its templates and other features. But how ever you can play around while starting up an angular project and can use *vite*. [Click here](https://medium.com/@hiepxanh/angular-vite-example-is-crazy-fast-3ee4d730020c) to read the whole article.